# Change part of string into *

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have an IBAN: `NL20INGB0001234567`

How can I change all digits except the last 4 into `*`:

```
Input: NL20INGB0001234567
Output: NL20INGB******4567
```

**all digits but NL*20***

Comment: *all digits* but NL**20** ??

Comment: exactly, all digits but NL**20**

Comment: Is the IBAN a fixed length, where the numbers you want to turn into `****` always start and end at position 9 and 14, respectively?

Comment: You mean you want to convert only the trailing digits?

Comment: yes, only the trailing digits

Comment: Does every string start: NL20INGB or NL?

Comment: Will the IBAN always have the format of `########******####`? Exactly that many characters in each string?

Comment: it will always start with a 2 letter country code + 2 control numbers

Comment: then `NL` is a country code and `20INGB` are control numbers?

Comment: 20 is the control number

Comment: ...So is `INGB` always going to be in the string, or do you want to convert it to `****`'s as well? It makes a difference whether or not the string will always have a predictable number of digits before you reach the `*` part.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.nordea.com/Our+services/International+products+and+services/Cash+Management/IBAN+countries/908462.html) the IBAN length can be anywhere from 16 to 30...

Comment: If what @beroe is saying is true *and* you need to account for that, let me know and I'll edit my solution to handle that case.

Comment: Also, @nelsonvarela, don't forget to upvote the most helpful answer here so that user can get points!

Comment: @joaquin, etc This doesn't seem overly "off-topic". It is poorly specified, and they didn't show what they tried, but it is a relatively tricky programming question that generated a respectable number of responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = 'NL20INGB0001234567'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)(?=\d{4}$)', lambda m:'*'*len(m.group(1)), strs)
'NL20INGB******4567'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest?

```
import re
s='NL20INGB0001234567'
re.sub(r'\d+(\d{4})$',r'****\1',s)
```

Result:

```
'NL20INGB****4567'
```

Comment: It is hard when the question is edited under your feet..! This will just put 4 stars, obviously, as originally posted, and not the exact number for the digits. If the length is always the same, you can change the number of `*`.

Comment: regex is rarely if ever the "simplest" ... but yeah this should work fine ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, I probably should have said "this seems simpler than some of the other answers that are posited". The old "[now you have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)" situation...

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = ''
iban = 'NL20INGB0001234567'
for i in iban[4:-4]:
     if i.isdigit():
             tmp += '*'
     else:
             tmp += i

iban = iban[:4] + tmp + iban[-4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> iban = "NL20INGB0001234567"
>>> iban[:4] + ''.join(i if i.isalpha() else "*" for i in iban[4:-4]) + iban[-4:]
'NL20INGB******4567'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "IBAN: NL20INGB0001234567"

s = [ele for ele in s.split(':')[-1] if ele.strip()]

mask = [1 for ele in range(len(s) - 10)] + [0] * 6 + [1] * 4

print ''.join(["*" if mask[i] == 0 else ele for i, ele in enumerate(s)])
```

Output:

```
NL20INGB******4567
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you worded the question, I'm assuming you want to format an `IBAN` string from

```
##################
```

to

```
########******####
```

Based on this, a simple solution is to write this function:

```
def ConverterFunction(IBAN):
    return IBAN[:8]+"******"+IBAN[14:]
```

and call it with this line:

```
ConverterFunction(<your IBAN here>)
```

Of course, attaching assignments or `prints` where necessary.

EDIT: A bit of an explanation might be necessary, too.

Whatever you are using as `IBAN` is a string, and strings can be `sliced`. By slicing, a person can pick up parts of a string and leave others behind. It uses the index of each letter's position, like so:

```
This is OK
0123456789
```

Note, the index always starts at `0`, not `1`.

Example of taking string slices:

```
examplestring = "EXAMPLE!"
print examplestring[:3] # "[:3]" means "from beginning to position 3"
print examplestring[5:] # "[5:]" means "from position 5 to end of string"
print examplestring[3:5] # "[3:5]" means "from position 3 to position 5"
```

Output:

```
>> EXAM
>> LE!
>> MPL
```

So in my solution, what the function `ConverterFunction(IBAN)` does is:

```
#Takes string "IBAN"
#Chops off the beginning and end parts you want to save
#Puts them back together with "******" in the middle
```

Understand?

Happy coding!

Comment: The problem with a length-based solution instead of a context-based one is that IBANs can be 16-30 characters long...

Comment: If our friend above here has to do with that, the length-based solution can continue by using *negative indexes* to save the last four letters of a string regardless of the middle content, though I understand what you are saying.

Comment: I thought about negative indices, but that assumes the same number of letters at the beginning, and only the number of digits vary. Clearly the OP requirements been to be better defined in any case!

Comment: I've tried to assure all of these conditions with the poster. My answer is based on these conditions and assures us of that.